# Trying to get the Android LocalNotification plugins for phonegap to work in cordova-1.6.0

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, localnotification

I'm trying to upgrade a phonegap-1.4.1 project  that uses the LocalNotification plugin for Android  to cordova-1.6.0

I found this link here: https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/pull/109
Where it says, For Android: use this.ctx.getContext() method of CordovaInterface object to get Conext object.

I edited LocalNotification.java and got my project to compile without errors by changing the following lines:

## From:

```
alarm = new AlarmHelper(this.ctx);
...
final SharedPreferences alarmSettings = this.ctx.getSharedPreferences(PLUGIN_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
...
final Editor alarmSettingsEditor = this.ctx.getSharedPreferences(PLUGIN_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
...
final Editor alarmSettingsEditor = this.ctx.getSharedPreferences(PLUGIN_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
...
final Editor alarmSettingsEditor = this.ctx.getSharedPreferences(PLUGIN_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

## To:

```
alarm = new AlarmHelper(this.ctx.getContext());
...
final SharedPreferences alarmSettings = this.ctx.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PLUGIN_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
...
final Editor alarmSettingsEditor = this.ctx.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PLUGIN_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
...
final Editor alarmSettingsEditor = this.ctx.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PLUGIN_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
...
final Editor alarmSettingsEditor = this.ctx.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PLUGIN_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

However I must admit that I don't really know what I'm doing and the notifications don't work  and I don't get any errors in the applications log :(

Also just noticed that as per the example  in my  onDeviceReady() function  I have the following:

```
console.log("Device ready");

if (typeof plugins !== "undefined") {
   plugins.localNotification.add({
      date : new Date(),
      message : "Phonegap - Local Notification\r\nSubtitle comes after linebreak",
      ticker : "This is a sample ticker text",
      repeatDaily : false,
      id : 4
   });
}
```

If I remove the the if condition typeof plugins !== "undefined" then I get an error in my app log which is: Uncaught ReferenceError: plugins is not defined

I guess something else as changed in cordova.  If there is a guide somewhere for upgrading android plugins to cordova  if would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgraded to Cordova-1.6.1 today and it now works ;)

Brave enough to admit  that it might have been  a "chair/keyboard" interface issue.
Think when I upgraded to 1.6.0 I forgot to change it in the header of my index.html

Comment: Does the `localNotification.cancelAll` work for you? https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/issues/549

Comment: Just tried in my project  which uses cordova-1.6.1 and your right cancelAll doesn't work. I didn't notice before because I cancel using the id.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like [getContext()](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/api/CordovaInterface.java) has been depreciated. Is there a cleaner solution to this issue?

Comment: I think getActivity() is the replacement method for this.

Comment: Yes it is... cordova.getActivity()