# "plugins is not defined" in PhoneGap Application

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am currently trying to use the **PhoneGap LocalNotification Plugin**, 
using Android 4.1 together with Cordova 2.0.0 and Sketcha (UI Library).

**UPDATE #2 20/9/12: I've used Bozzzi's code with some fixes:**

1. Added }) to the end of localnotification.js (syntax error).
2. changed `cordova.define("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification", function(require, exports, module)` to:
   `cordova.define("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification", function(require, exports, module)`,
   so the modules name will match for this function (before the module wasn't found):

   > window.plugins.LocalNotification =
   >   cordova.require("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification");
3. change from this:

   > if (!window.plugins) {
   >           window.plugins = {};
   >       }
   >       else if (!window.plugins.LocalNotification) {
   >           window.plugins.LocalNotification = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification");
   >       }

to this:

```
if (!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}

if (!window.plugins.LocalNotification) {
    window.plugins.LocalNotification = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification");
}
```

before this change, if window.plugins is not found, it will be created but the window.plugins.LocalNotification wouldn't.

After all these fixes I am getting this error:

> ```
> > 09-20 01:22:27.355: D/CordovaLog(8297):
> > file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 21 : PAPA AMERICANO ready
> > 09-20 01:22:27.360: I/Web Console(8297): PAPA AMERICANO ready at
> > file:///android_asset/www/index.html:21 09-20 01:22:27.370:
> > D/CordovaLog(8297): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of
> > undefined 09-20 01:22:27.375: D/CordovaLog(8297):
> > file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 35 : Uncaught TypeError:
> > Cannot call method 'add' of undefined 09-20 01:22:27.375: E/Web
> > Console(8297): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of
> > undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:35 09-20
> > 01:22:29.185: D/DroidGap(8297): onMessage(spinner,stop) 09-20
> > 01:22:30.255: E/SKIA(8297): FimgApiStretch:stretch failed 09-20
> > 01:22:41.755: E/SKIA(8297): FimgApiStretch:stretch failed 09-20
> > 01:22:52.565: D/CordovaWebView(8297): >>> loadUrlNow() 09-20
> > 01:22:52.565: D/webkit(8297): Firewall not null 09-20 01:22:52.565:
> > D/webkit(8297): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
> ```

For some reason the `cordova.require("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification")` dont set the `window.plugins.LocalNotification` value and it keeps being undefined.
Here is my updated index.html (Update #2):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AndroidSencha</title>
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="LocalNotification.js"></script>
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript">

    function onDeviceReady() {
        if (!window.plugins) {
            window.plugins = {};
        } else if (!window.plugins.LocalNotification) {
            window.plugins.LocalNotification = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification");
        }
    }

    window.document.addEventListener("deviceready", appReady, false);

    function appReady() {
        console.log("PAPA AMERICANO ready");

        var d = new Date();
        d = d.getTime() + 2 * 1000; //60 seconds from now
        d = new Date(d);

        if (!window.plugins) {
            window.plugins = {};
        }

        if (!window.plugins.LocalNotification) {
            window.plugins.LocalNotification = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification");
        }

        window.plugins.localNotification.add({
            date: d,
            message: 'This is an Android alarm using the statusbar',
            id: 123
        });
    }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
         /**
         * Example of an initial loading indicator.
         * It is recommended to keep this as minimal as possible to provide instant feedback
         * while other resources are still being loaded for the first time
         */
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #1985D0
        }

    </style>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
.loadingText{
color: white;
font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 10%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="appLoadingIndicator">
    <div class="loadingText"><div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Loading, Please wait..</div>
    <div><img src="resources\images\smileloading.gif"></div></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my localnotificaiton.js after my fixes (Update #2):

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification", function(require, exports, module) {      

var exec = require("cordova/exec");
var LocalNotification = function () {};

LocalNotification.prototype.add = function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                date : new Date(),
                message : '',
                ticker : '',
                repeatDaily : false,
                id : ""
            };
        if (options.date) {
                options.date = (options.date.getMonth()) + "/" + (options.date.getDate()) + "/"
                        + (options.date.getFullYear()) + "/" + (options.date.getHours()) + "/"
                        + (options.date.getMinutes());
            }

            for ( var key in defaults) {
                if (typeof options[key] !== "undefined")
                    defaults[key] = options[key];
            }

            cordova.exec(null, null, "LocalNotification", "add",  new Array(defaults));
};

LocalNotification.prototype.cancel = function(notificationId) {
    cordova.exec(null, null, 'LocalNotification', 'cancel', new Array({
        id : notificationId
    }));
};

LocalNotification.prototype.cancelAll = function() {
    cordova.exec(null, null, 'LocalNotification', 'cancelAll', new Array());
};


var LocalNotification = new LocalNotification();
module.exports = LocalNotification
});
```

**UPDATE #1:** I've already added the plugin to the plugins.xml file:

```
<plugins>
...
  <plugin name="LocalNotification" value="com.phonegap.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification"/>
...
</plugins>
```

I've done the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification) and replaced the broken java expressions as mentioned [here](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/phonegap-android-plugins-sometimes-we.html).

Unfortunately, when I run the application I get the following error (Both in emulator and device):

> 09-16 16:46:16.330: E/Web Console(27875): Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   plugins is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:74

[This guy was facing the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218745/trying-to-get-the-android-localnotification-plugins-for-phonegap-to-work-in-cord) but I've referenced the cordova javascript file in my index.html and its still not working.

This is how my package explorer looks like (You might find something missing):
*I am not sure if I should have plugins.xml or have config.xml and have the plugins in it,
I have both just in case*

[image: Package Explorer]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed LocalNotification.js so you can copy code. It works with cordova 2.0 (tested!)

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/js/LocalNotification", function(require, exports, module) {      

var exec = require("cordova/exec");
var LocalNotification = function () {};

LocalNotification.prototype.add = function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                date : new Date(),
                message : '',
                ticker : '',
                repeatDaily : false,
                id : ""
            };
        if (options.date) {
                options.date = (options.date.getMonth()) + "/" + (options.date.getDate()) + "/"
                        + (options.date.getFullYear()) + "/" + (options.date.getHours()) + "/"
                        + (options.date.getMinutes());
            }

            for ( var key in defaults) {
                if (typeof options[key] !== "undefined")
                    defaults[key] = options[key];
            }

            cordova.exec(null, null, "LocalNotification", "add",  new Array(defaults));
};

LocalNotification.prototype.cancel = function(notificationId) {
    cordova.exec(null, null, 'LocalNotification', 'cancel', new Array({
        id : notificationId
    }));
};

LocalNotification.prototype.cancelAll = function() {
    cordova.exec(null, null, 'LocalNotification', 'cancelAll', new Array());
};


var LocalNotification = new LocalNotification();
module.exports = LocalNotification;
```

});

*now you can call the notif. with:*

```
    datum = '2012-09-20 15:51:00';  
tt1 = datum.split(/[- :]/);
    dd = new Date(tt1[0], tt1[1]-1, tt1[2], tt1[3], tt1[4], tt1[5]);

window.plugins.LocalNotification.add({ date: dd, message: "Some message", ticker : "Some ticker", repeatDaily : false, id: 1234 });
```

Comment: And dont forget:
`
function onDeviceReady() { 
  if (!window.plugins) {
   window.plugins = {};
   }
   else
  if (!window.plugins.LocalNotification) {
   window.plugins.LocalNotification = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification");
   }
}
`

Comment: Firest of all, I really appreciate your help. I've tried your code and struggled with it alot and fixed some things in order to make it work. have a look in the main post, I've mentioned the steps I've done so see whether they are good or bad. weird that its working for you as is while I having problems :(

Comment: You can take a look at source at [link]http://bozzzi.mine.nu/Aviran/

If you find difficulties with code I will upload Eclipse project for you. You can see from screenshot that when I click on "Try me" I activate notification in emulator...

Comment: I will watch the source code as I come from work. however, it would be great if you can upload the eclipse project in case I wont be able to make it work. thanks

Comment: I have a question with this one. "cordova/plugin/js/LocalNotification"

What does that mean? the location of LocalNotification? Is that the JS file?

Comment: @Dreyfus15 have you gotten your answer on that question cause I still want to know too.

Answer (score 4):

The plugin's .js has not been updated to the 2.0.0 specification. Take a look at one of my more recent blog posts on how to write a plugin that conforms to the 2.0.0 spec.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/08/so-you-wanna-write-phonegap-200-android.html

Comment: I didn't have time to read this, i will read it tomorrow. thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

Check the latest Plugin update for cordova 2.2
[LocalNotification 2.2](https://github.com/moumen-o/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification)

Answer (score 0):

use window.plugin not plugin alone and see what happens.

Comment: I've replaced the plugin with window.plugin and i get this error:
09-16 19:00:26.700: D/CordovaLog(524): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localNotification' of undefined
09-16 19:00:26.700: D/CordovaLog(524): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 74 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localNotification' of undefined
09-16 19:00:26.700: E/Web Console(524): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localNotification' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:74

Comment: just to clarify, its "plugins" not "plugin".

Comment: did you add localnotification plugin to plugins.xml ?

Comment: Yes, I've already added the plugin to the plugins.xml file (I've updated both plugins.xml and config.xml).

I've updated my post with the plugin configuration.

Comment: Does the question reflect the current state of your index.html?

Comment: Devgeeks, you mean if the index.html code here is the exact one that I have problems with? yes.